# Expo: Facebook native ads not displaying image

Tags: expo, facebook-audience-network

After running test, the ad text display correctly, it displayed:

**Your ad integration works. Whoohoo!**

But no image displayed. I thought the `<AdMediaView>` show do the work, but it doesn't. What's wrong with my code?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';
FacebookAds.AdSettings.addTestDevice(FacebookAds.AdSettings.currentDeviceHash);

const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager('my id', 1);
import AdComponent from './fbads.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello!!</Text>
        <View>
        <AdComponent adsManager={adsManager} />
      </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

fbads.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';
const { AdTriggerView, AdMediaView } = FacebookAds;


class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AdMediaView />
        <AdTriggerView>
          <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
        </AdTriggerView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still encounters this problem, try setting a fix width and height for the AdMediaView, and it should display after that.  For example:

```
<AdMediaView style={{width: 400, height: 300}}/>
```

The same thing applies to AdIconView:

```
<AdIconView style={{width: 50, height: 50}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, today I met this issue again. After a long time testing, I found that to show the image, I **must** place both `AdIconView` and `AdMediaView`.

#### This works:

```
<AdIconView style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
<AdMediaView style={{width: 300, height: 200}} />
<AdTriggerView>
    <Text>a{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
</AdTriggerView>
```

#### This doesn't work:

```
<AdMediaView style={{width: 300, height: 200}} />
<AdTriggerView>
    <Text>a{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
</AdTriggerView>
```

#### Neither this:

```
<AdIconView style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
<AdTriggerView>
    <Text>a{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
</AdTriggerView>
```